# external function call, promise, async and Mongo - confused

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, async-await

Beginning to feel really thick here. Read a lot and I believe I understand promises and async-await decently well. However, I seem to struggle to use the function elsewhere, such that I can obtain the result (e.g. i get pending in another js file with: let dbConnection = dbOperations.openDatabaseConnection();).

Could someone explain to me why do I keep getting pending from the below functions (same function written with promise and asyncawait)? I can console.log the dbConnection result as expected prior to my return within the function. Also, I am particularly keen to understand promises in this sense, as it seems that many npm packages seem to return promises (and with my experience at least the async-await does not sit well with that? -> using async does not wait for resolve in my experience).

// Establish database connection

```
function openDatabaseConnection() {

    let dbConnection = {};

    return mongodb.connect(dbUri).then(conn => {
        dbConnection.connection = conn;
        return dbConnection;
    })
    .then(() => {
        dbConnection.session = dbConnection.connection.db(dbName);
        //console.log(dbConnection);
        return dbConnection;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
};
```

// Establish database connection

```
async function openDatabaseConnection() {

    let dbConnection = {};

    try {
        dbConnection.connection = await mongodb.connect(dbUri);
        dbConnection.session = await dbConnection.connection.db(dbName);
    } finally {
        //console.log(dbConnection);
        return dbConnection;
    };
};
```

Comment: What does "I keep getting pending" mean?

Comment: It'd make more sens if your `then` accepted the returned connection, then you don't need the `let dbConnection`, i.e. `.then((dbConnection) => {dbConnection.session...`

Comment: Thanks Liam, noticed you contributed to the answer below as well which explains this very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions return again a promise.

So in your statement `let dbConnection = dbOperations.openDatabaseConnection();` 
you assign a promise.

Thus you need to do something like:

```
dbOperations.openDatabaseConnection().then((dbConn) => ..)
```

or

```
let dbConnection = await dbOperations.openDatabaseConnection();
```

(note this requires to be wrapped in an `async` function)

Comment: Thank you! Very clear, seems so obvious now. One additional question related to the difference between using promises and async-await. The await above seems so very neat, in the sense that I can declare a variable in a way that it is visible throughout my file. Is this possible with promises, or is it that e.g. above to use the dbConn I would have to operate within the arrow function? or is it possible to extract the variable outside of that function? Wanted to upvote, but not enough rep yet to do so

Comment: that's actually the usage of async/await - just syntax sugar that allows you to write asynchronous (promised) code in a synchronous fashion - does not offer any other advantage compared to native promises. 
With async await your variable is also just visible in the current async function scope, not that different as in `.then((dbConn) => { .. })` right? :)

Comment: ah, did not realise :) still drilling on the promise point, so that it would be equivalently usable as the async where I can: let dbConnection = await..., would it simply be: let dbConnection = dbOperations.openDatabaseConnection().then((dbConn) => ..)?

Comment: Trying it this way it did not seem to work at least (albeit did not try many variations, aside from return) -> leads to pending again when logging it outside of that function (whereas with async I can log it outside of the function e.g. below the let dbConnection = await...). With promise one of the tried ones: let dbConnection = dbOperations.openDatabaseConnection().then((dbConn) => {
    dbConnection = dbConn;
});

console.log(dbConnection);

Comment: With promises you have the fulfilled data only available in the function - therefore you pass it, so upon settlement the function may be called with the data. With the support of Iterators/Generators in JS (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) async/await was added simply as syntax sugar. Did you already check https://www.promisejs.org/generators/ ? Could help you to better understand promises and with generators/iterators how async/await works

Answer (score 0):

Async/await is just another way to work with Promises, just don't wait for something that isn't a Promise.

```
async function openDatabaseConnection() {

  let dbConnection = {};

  try {
    dbConnection.connection = await mongodb.connect(dbUri);
    // await here does not make sense, this function does not return a Promise
    // dbConnection.session = await dbConnection.connection.db(dbName);
    dbConnection.session = dbConnection.connection.db(dbName);
  } finally {
    //console.log(dbConnection);
    // return will always execute, keep here only when it should
    // return an empty object if the connection fails
    return dbConnection;
  };
};
```

[More info on async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: Thank you! Good comments to help me understand parts that seem to be shady still on these.